# Multiple geo properties (array) per document

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am looking at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798930.aspx:

There is an example for a location field which is a single geo point.  This and the further ability to geo search around a point is fantastic, however in real life situations there are quite often multiple geo points associated with a single entity.  One example would be the multiple locations a job opening can be filled at.  Further interpreting that only string arrays are allowed, I am extrapolating that geo point arrays per document are not allowed in azure search right now.

Is that correct?  And how would you implement this without 2 roundtrips (to a second index where ids of documents are associated with geo points)?

One could probably create 4-5 geo fields and search around each one (OR'd) in a filter, but that would limit the number and I am not sure it is even technically possible to OR multiple geo searches like distance(loc1) < 50 OR distance(loc2) < 50 OR etc...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct, we don't currently support arrays of geo points. If you have a reasonable higher boundary for the number of geo points you might have, your approach of having multiple fields and using an "or" filter would work.

Comment: Thanks Pablo - are arrays of other types, including geo points on the roadmap?  One would have to be able to call something like this in the search filter though: loc/any(p: distance(p, reference_p) < 50)

Comment: Yes, we would like to do generalize arrays at some point. There are a number of issues we need to work out before we commit to a plan, but I agree that this would be generally useful.